# React - Webpack вопрос про module.exports

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, webpack, модули

Смотрю курс Webpack для React.js на ютубе, автор видеоролика продемонстрировал файл content.jsx где используется `require` и `module.exports`

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

сказав, что "используя require мы делаем ссылку на папку **react** и так же для **react-dom**, затем экспортируем класс Content", мой вопрос такой почему вместо require не использует `import React from 'react'` для **react-dom** `import React from 'react-dom'` а экспорт `export Content` или `export default Content`

Comment: Это особенность не webpack, а самого js.

Comment: Кроме того, вы скорее всего смотрите старое видео, в котором используется старый способ импортирования. Новый, который вы описали прекрасно работает сейчас и в вебпак.